# how do you create a tree rule given tags and metric in opentsdb

Tags: opentsdb

I can create a tree with this:

```
http://localhost:4242/api/tree?name=GraphiteTree&method_override=post
```

I can create rule based on metrics:

```
http://localhost:4242/api/tree/rule?treeid=1&level=0&order=0&type=METRIC&separator=\.&method_override=post
```

I really need to combine tag and metric type to create a rule based tree in opentsdb. My data looks like this:

My data in opentsdb looks like this:

```
pcpu 1356998400 42.5 host=web1.example.com
used_memory 1356998400 60 host=web1.example.com

pcpu 1356998400 10 vGuest=guest1.example.com
used_memory 1356998400 60 vGuest=guest1.example.com

disk_capacity 1356998400 42.5 disk=nas1.example.com
used_disk  1356998400 42.5 disk=nas1.example.com
```

There does not seem be a lot of docs about this. I am hoping that somebody has done something like this. How would I go about creating a rule for tags and metrics combined, as shown above?